# QTabBar with One Tab is Too Wide

Tags: c++, qt, qt4.7

My widget structure is as follows:
QToolBar with a QTabBar added to it and a QToolButton added after the TabBar.

By default, there will only be one tab open, and the ToolButton functions to open more tabs. (Like the tab interface for Google Chrome)

The problem I run into is that when there is only one tab, the TabBar allocates more space than necessary (looks like: size_of_tab(0) * 2) When I add extra tabs, the button aligns nicely with the TabBar, but as soon as I close them down to only 1 tab there is extra space again.

I have tried messing with the horizontalSizePolicy and programmatically setting the width, but neither worked.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried with a layout and Horizontal Expander?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the style-sheet of the `QTabBar::tab` as follows, before doing this remove all the changes you have in the code which affect the tab size. You cab adjust `100px` value to suit your requirement.

```
QTabBar::tab 
{
 min-width: 100px;
 max-width: 100px;
}
```